# java inserting an element using listIterator

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, listiterator

I m building a graph coloring allocator for a toy programming language. While generating spill code sometimes i have to insert before the current instruction a load {for restoring} or an insert after the current instruction { for spilling }. My code is represented as a graph with a node for each basic block and an list of instructions within the block,

I generate a dfs ordered list of graph nodes and for each node i traverse the instruction list within the node, 
using codeList.listIterator() i can go back and forth via next and previous respectively and do an add for insert after and insert before.

How should the insertion happen right at the beginning of the list using add() method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From ListIterator.add API

```
The element is inserted immediately before the element that would be returned by next(), if any, and after the element that would be returned by previous(), if any. (If the list contains no elements, the new element becomes the sole element on the list.) The new element is inserted before the implicit cursor: a subsequent call to next would be unaffected, and a subsequent call to previous would return the new element.
```

Here is an example of how it works in practice

```
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    l.add("1");
    ListIterator<String> i = l.listIterator();
    i.add("2");
    while (i.hasPrevious()) {
        i.previous();
    }
    i.add("3");
    System.out.println(l);
```

output

```
[3, 2, 1]
```

and we could do more tricks with ListIterator

Comment: @jahroy "How should the insertion happen right at the beginning of the list using add() method?" No, this is exactly what he wants. And using a fresh iterator will throw an exception (`ConcurrentModificationException`) if he tries to call `next` or `previous` on the old iterator. He'll have to modify his `for` loop or whatever he's using to accommodate the new call so that `next` hasn't been called when he calls `add`.

Comment: @jahroy you're way off. This answer is correct. Maybe Evgeniy should show more navigation before calling add, but getting another listiterator completely won't work

Comment: Consider the point where my list has only 1. I take the list iterator and do a next, now the cursor will implicitly be pointing after 1 and my 'nextval' will be pointing to 1, if i do a hasprevious() check and then do previous then my cursor will be pointing before 1 and 'prevval' will be pointing to 1.(could be a vanilla last val pointer!) so now an insertion happens at the beginning? is my intuition right here?

Comment: The best way to understand it is to experiment with it. Simply put your scenario in a couple of lines of code and run it.